# How To Handle Value Objects Within Classes?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

When I learned about dependency injection, I read "every" class dependency should be injected (let's ignore interfaces for now).

Recently shifted to using value objects instead of associativee arrays (within repo's etc.) Most tutorials I have read instantiate the value objects within class methods (no dependency injection). This isn't a big deal for the value object but why is this path chosen vs dependency injecting in repo constructor then cloning blank value object?

I am not trying to micro optimize, mainly trying to adhere to and learn best practices.

The only reason I can think of to avoid cloning route would be constructor injection of value object data, but even then couldn't the constructor be called after cloning?

Ex:

```
class Repo {
    public function getUser() {
        return new UserValueObject($userDataProvidedByDB);
    }
}
```

VS

```
class Repo {

    public function __construct(UserValueObject $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return (clone $this->user)->__construct($userDataProvidedByDB);
    }
}
```

Comment: A value object should only contain properties, (except from a possible constructor, getters and setters) which the rest of the application uses. If you would inject some other value object with a different set of properties, your application would most likely fail either way.

Comment: The empty user 'value object'/'entity' is populated with data from db and returned by repo. When creating repo a clean instance of the `User` class is injected so each clone is empty as if it were instantiated within the repo. Only real difference here is injecting clean entity in repo constructor. ( Unless I misunderstood )

Comment: Let's break it down. **1.** A repo always need to return objects with the exact same set of properties, so the rest of the application knows what it contains. **2.** A value object doesn't contain any business logic, it is (or at least should) only store values in it's properties. **Conclusion**, mocking/changing the value object (sending in another value object into the constructor) would mean that you would still need to change all the code that uses the value object (unless it had the same set of properties but then why change it?) to use the new properties and then DI has lost it's purpose

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your question while reading, it is more about the problem of instantiating objects (not `new`-ing inside of class, to be more precise).

In a good many of cases, it is quite acceptable to instantiate the object inside of `Repository`. Just because

> This isn't a big deal

for most simple cases, and having all that db stuff being implemented the latest one (or somewhen about then), when you already have the classes that `Repository` is supposed to return implemented. That lets tests for the `Repository` not to fail because of faults in the class to be returned, and makes these tests more functional/integration rather than unit, though.

But there could be more complicated cases. One example could be when the class returned (`User`, if taking your question) is supposed to have some rich behaviour and thus uses some services that are to be injected via constructor. That would force `Repository` to have far too much knowledge about totally irrelevant things so it could instantiate the `User`. Another example could be the situation when a developer doesn't have knowledge about what and how to be instantiated with the data that `Respository` fetches.

These situations force us to abstract all such irrelevant knowledge and functionality out of the class, and have some third object injected into `Repository` to do that job. So it could look like:

```
interface UserFactoryInterface
{
    public function makeUserFromRawArray();
}


class Repo
{
    private $factory;

    public function __construct(UserFactoryInterface $factory) {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->factory->makeUserFromRawArray($userDataProvidedByDB);
    }
}
```

So the concrete implementation of `UserFactoryInterface` knows how to create the `User` having raw data from db and managing anything else on its own. `Repository` does not depend on things it should not depend on, it just gets the service for creating from outside.

Again, I believe the question is more about the problem of instantiating objects and separation of concerns, rather than specifically about [`Value objects`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) which I'd rather name [`DTO`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) or even [`LocalDTO`](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/LocalDTO.html) respectively for the case you posted.